# ostream<<Iterator, C++

Tags: c++, iterator, ostream

I'm trying to build an operator which prints list,
Why won't ostream<<*it compile?

```
void operator<<(ostream& os, list<class T> &lst)
{
     list<T>::iterator it;
     for(it = lst.begin(); it!=lst.end(); it++)
     {
                  os<<*it<<endl; //This row
     }
}
```

Comment: Did you look at the error messages ? And what did they say ?

Comment: Welcome to SO, I hope you read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask).

Answer (score 3):

Because `*it` does not implement stream insertion. That is, there is no overload for `operator<<` that takes an `ostream` and a `T`. Note that you should be returning the `ostream& os` to allow operator chaining. Also your function template definition looks wrong. Consider doing this instead:

```
template< typename T >
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, list<T> const& lst)
{
    std::copy(
        lst.begin(), lst.end()
      , std::ostream_iterator< T >( os )
    );
    return os;
}
```

or better yet, to support streams over all kind of elements and traits:

```
template< typename Elem, typename Traits, typename T >
std::basic_ostream< Elem, Traits >& operator<<(
    std::basic_ostream< Elem, Traits >& os
  , std::list<T> const& lst
)
{
    std::copy(
        lst.begin(), lst.end()
      , std::ostream_iterator< T >( os )
    );
    return os;
}
```

Adittionaly, you can pass a separator to `std::ostream_iterator` constructor to be inserted between each element.

*** Update: ***
I just noticed that even if your function template declaration were correct, you would be dealing with a dependent type. The iterator is dependent on the type `T`, so you need to tell this to the compiler:

```
typename list<T>::iterator it;
```

Comment: But I actually can make like:  
cout<<*it<<endl; //it is an iterator for list<int>

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in your template declaration. The following should compile and work just fine:

```
template <typename T>
void operator<<(ostream& os, list<typename T> &lst)
{
      list<T>::iterator it;
      for(it = lst.begin(); it!=lst.end(); it++)
      {
                  os<<*it<<endl;
      }
}
```

This is provided of course that the element type of your list can actually be used with the `<<` operator of an `ostream`.

Answer (score 1):

You are using template syntax the wrong way:

```
template<class T>
void operator<<(ostream& os, list<T> &lst)
{
    list<T>::iterator it;
    for(it = lst.begin(); it!=lst.end(); it++)
    {
        os<<*it<<endl; //This row
    }
}
```

And by the way, you should return a reference to the stream to allow chaining of output operators, and the list should be const, and you can also use the standard library for doing the output loop:

```
template<class T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::list<T> &lst)
{
    std::copy(lst.begin(), lst.end(), std::ostream_iterator<T>(os, "\n"));
    return os;
}
```

Comment: The compiler makes an error on the "list<T>::iterator it" row,
expected `;' before "it"

Comment: @Taru Are you sure the compiler knows `list`? Have you included <list> and made it visible (with either using `std::list` or `using namespace std`, which is actually not recommended)?

Comment: @TaruStolovich Ah yes, K-ballo has solved the iterator declaration issue. I always forget about `typename`.

Answer (score -1):

**Rewrite to:**

```
template<class T>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, list<T>& lst){
    typename list<T>::iterator it;
    for(it = lst.begin(); it != lst.end(); ++it){
                 os << *it << endl;
    }
    return os;
}
```

Comment: And this answer was neccessary because...? And by the way, `lst` should be const reference.